# Can’t acces Docker container on localhost

Tags: angular, docker, build, local

I have a front app who uses Angular-cli and i’am trying to check if it works proprely separetly before integrating it in the container core but it seems that i can’t get acces to the localhost.
I’am using a macOS Catalina 10.15.7 with Docker Desktop.

And it's not the same problem as others because i already tested before asking my question in stackoverflow so don't put as duplicate, THANK YOU !!

My Dockerfile is build like this:

```
FROM    node:14-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app/front

#COPY    ./angular-cli .
COPY    package.json package-lock.json
COPY    . .       

RUN     npm install 
RUN     npm install -g @angular/cli

EXPOSE  4200
# Angular installation if it fails, 

CMD     ["ng", "serve"]
```

And when i run the app with the command:

```
docker run -d -p 80:4200 reponame
```

My build works perfectly and shows me this:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Compiled successfully.
```

and when i go to Localhost:4200 it shows that the page is not accessible.
i also tried to connect with Ip adress using this commands but same thing.

```
docker inspect -f ‘{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}’ imagename
```

i also tried to change different ports because i read in Mac the port 80 might be broken or smth so i tried:

```
docker run -d -p 4200:4200 appname
docker run -d -p 8080:4200 appname
```

If anyone can help me, would really greatfull.
Thanks !

Comment: What do you think `-p 80:4200` does?

Comment: Sending any traffic from the app port to the docker port ?

Comment: But _which_ ports? Read https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: my app port is in 4200 to 80, and i tried to go in localhost:80 same thing

Comment: You need an `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` option.  If a server ever prints out "listening on localhost:12345` in its startup messages, it won't be reachable from outside its own container.

Comment: @DavidMaze hmm even if i already specified it in my package.json, i should do it again in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: You specify `CMD ["ng", "serve"]` in the Dockerfile.  It's fine to change that to _e.g._ `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` if you have a standard npm script to run the dev server.

Comment: Yes, i did the changes like you specified but nothing changed always the same result, idk the issue where it would be.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your app in the container is **NOT** exposed via the `0.0.0.0` interface.

So in your Angular app, change expose on `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` instead.

Update your CMD:

```
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Connect from your host system with `localhost:80`.

Comment: Good idea gona try it, didn't think of that.

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works.

Comment: hmm seems not working...

Comment: You changed `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` in your Dockerfile like @DavidMaze proposed?

Comment: Yes just waiting to build and telling you what happened but gona ask you the same question, if already specified it in my package.json, i should do it again in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: Yes you should add the line: `CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`

Comment: @Kuyper now i got this error when typing the run command in port 80.          
An unhandled exception occurred: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND O.O.O.O

See "/tmp/ng-aAAkli/angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: You used zero's in the container? And connect with localhost from the host system

Comment: Yes i did note zero's on the Dockerfile system, in the CMD["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"], Whzn you say connect with localhost, you mean enter in the Contaner and type the command "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0" ?

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper thank you for your suggestion, it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

your port mapping seems incorrect with what you are trying to achieve. *-p 80:4200* means that you would use port 80 on your host machine to access the application.

So you should try to access it through *http://localhost* or *http://localhost:80*. Even if that is not working, it sometimes happen that your port 80 is already bound to some other application. May be you can try a different port like 8080, 8888 etc instead of 80.

Comment: Well as i mentionned, it is as you said in http//localhost but if the port was already taken Docker would have told me that it is, no ?